# Spark from light switch

Tags: wiring, lighting

I just installed a new led switch in a box with two other switches. When I ran power to it and tested the non led switch in the box I received a big spark. I went and turned off power again, removed face plate, and realized the ground from the new switch was wrapped around screw on the switch next to it (the screw for live wire). I fixed the problem and ground wire has a burn mark on it from spark. Just wanted to know if it is safe or should I have an electrician come out to check for and damage or hazards?  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Did the breaker throw?

Comment: Not sure if the breaker blew. I had so many turned off at the time cause I had to narrow it down to three doffernt breakers that were all sending power to the box of three switches.

Comment: It’s all up and running now. Just wanted to make sure it wasn’t going to cause any problems in the future.

Comment: It usually just means you've lost a quarter to a half inch off one of the strands of your ground wire, and scared yourself.

Comment: can you upload a photo of the box & switched with the cover plate off? Did you disconnect wires on anything other than the one switch you were replacing?

Comment: Only disconnected the one switch I was replacing and when putting switch back in the ground got stuck on the screw terminal of the neighboring switch. I’ll upload a pic tomorrow when it’s daylight. Total darkness when I shut down power to those switches.

Answer (score 1):

Are there "backstab" connections between here and the service panel?  This is just the sort of surge overload tends to damage them and provoke them into later failure.

I would eliminate those and move them either to side screws, or if equipped, screw-to-clamp.